# Float vs Int behavior in df.set_index()

Tags: python, pandas

has set_index changed dramatically in the latest pandas release (0.8)? I'm having trouble getting it to work as expected:

My original attempt tried to set index on 'id'

```
ipdb> merged2['id']
16    130809
25    130687
32    130686
9      41736
22    131913
7     130691
33    129993
13    130680
28    134295
29    130708

ipdb> merged2.set_index('id')
```

> ```
> *** KeyError: 0
> ```

```
ipdb> [type(i) for i in merged2['id']]
[<type 'numpy.float64'>, <type 'numpy.float64'>, <type 'numpy.float64'>, <type 'numpy.float64'>, <type 'numpy.float64'>, <type 'numpy.float64'>, <type 'numpy.float64'>, <type 'numpy.float64'>, <type 'numpy.float64'>, <type 'numpy.float64'>]
```

The current index is int:

```
ipdb> merged2.index
Int64Index([16, 25, 32,  9, 22,  7, 33, 13, 28, 29])

ipdb> [type(i) for i in merged2.index]
[<type 'numpy.int64'>, <type 'numpy.int64'>, <type 'numpy.int64'>, <type 'numpy.int64'>, <type 'numpy.int64'>, <type 'numpy.int64'>, <type 'numpy.int64'>, <type 'numpy.int64'>, <type 'numpy.int64'>, <type 'numpy.int64'>]
```

A workaround tried to construct a new index:

```
ndx=range(len(merged2))
[type(i) for i in ndx]
[<type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>]


ipdb> merged2.set_index(ndx)
```

> ```
> *** KeyError: 'no item named 0'
> ```

Finally, mapping my index as int works:

```
merged2['id']=map(lambda x: int(x), merged2['id']
merged2.set_index('id')
```

Thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I can't seem to edit the question -- I'm referring to 0.8

Comment: Per Chang's answer below I am fairly certain there may be a bug deeper in pandas's indexing code that is causing the above error. We'll try to get the 0.8.1 release out in the next few days (a few remaining TODO items).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work for me on 0.8.1dev. Can you post a stack trace and/or what merged2 looks like? Also are you sure you're using pandas 0.8?

```
In [50]: import pandas as pd

In [51]: idx = pd.Index([16, 25, 32, 9, 22, 7, 33, 13, 28, 29])

In [52]: idx
Out[52]: Int64Index([16, 25, 32,  9, 22,  7, 33, 13, 28, 29])

In [53]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(idx), 3), idx, ['id', 1, 2])

In [54]: df
Out[54]: 
          id         1         2
16  0.351188  2.082303 -0.143037
25  0.633243 -1.731306  0.749934
32 -0.337893 -0.264249 -0.549856
9  -0.728056  0.786955  1.103877
22  1.131559 -0.255439 -0.397913
7  -1.384519  0.397626 -0.421481
33  1.356455  2.863659 -2.060498
13 -0.355786 -0.051383 -0.609486
28 -0.056607  0.767800  1.433946
29 -0.288202 -0.437992  0.843746

In [55]: df.set_index('id')
Out[55]: 
                  1         2
id                           
 0.351188  2.082303 -0.143037
 0.633243 -1.731306  0.749934
-0.337893 -0.264249 -0.549856
-0.728056  0.786955  1.103877
 1.131559 -0.255439 -0.397913
-1.384519  0.397626 -0.421481
 1.356455  2.863659 -2.060498
-0.355786 -0.051383 -0.609486
-0.056607  0.767800  1.433946
-0.288202 -0.437992  0.843746

In [56]: pd.__version__
Out[56]: '0.8.1.dev-e2633d4'
```

Comment: Thanks Chang & Wes. I'm definitely using 0.8, unless version.version is broken ;). I'll look forward to the new release.